# Move upper half line horizontaly while keeping lower half steady

Tags: inkscape

Let's say I want to extrude the upper half of the right wall of a rectangle. Thus, I added a new node right middle of other two and select the right side of the rectangle and move it holding right arrow key. And that's the end product:

[image]

However, that's not what I want. I want it like that:

[image]

How can I accomplish this task? Thanks a lot!

Comment: thats because you have only added one node, but your requirement is of two nodes, try adding one more and then adjust.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech is correct. count the nodes in both your examples. You'll see the difference right there.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech i already added it as you see in 2nd example. but its so hard to do because it must be very close(at the top tbh) to the other one. i am asking if there is a better way to do that

Comment: Two other options: use another rectangle, and subtract it from the first OR use the 'draw vertical and horizontal lines only' mode of the Bézier tool to draw the figure.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new node (double click or Ctrl+Alt+click on the path). Switch on cusp node snapping.

[image]

Drag and snap the new node exactly to the other node.

[image]

Select and move the segment.

[image]